# Booststrap v5 textform class="form-label" prepopulate data in a way that can be copied to clipboard

Tags: textarea, bootstrap-5

Using bootstrap 5, specifically going over this:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/form-control/

I am trying to create a simple example text area with some text in it pre-populated, so that I can add a button that will copy the propulated text into clipboard.

Method 1-

Sample code from Bootstrap looks like this:

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Example textarea</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

If I use something like 'placeholder' the text box gets prepopulated but I can't "grab" that text neither manually or via a js script. The placeholder my understaning is just a hint of what is to be filled out in the box.

Method 2-

If I used for example a regular HTML textarea element I can do this, no problem, with something like this:

```
<textarea id="textbox" rows="3" cols="80">{{prepopulated_date_variable}}</textarea><br />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"onclick="copyTextBoxData()">Copy Copy Data</button>
```

So if I use a regular "textbox" like in Method 2, it does not leverage the cool look and resizing capabilities of bootstrap, hence why I am trying to get Method 1- or similar to work.

Any queues? tips?  maybe another element?

I am new to this all, but the concept is that I am passing from a another piece of code the prepopulated data for user to see (leveraging Jinja template with Python if that makes any difference) and then idea is that button allows my user to copy to mem clipboard what is in the text box, so that they can past in something else.

Appreciate any support or ideas.

I am using Method 2- described in problem statement. What I am expecting is that I can use Method 1 or alternative with bootstrap component to leverabe the styling and features of bootstrap.

Comment: It's not clear what "cool look and resizing capabilities" means here. Please revise to simplify your post and explain better what outcome you're after. Also update your title. It implies that you need help with clipboard functionality, but that doesn't seem to be your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to set the value of the form inputs when the page loads.

This code creates a form with two inputs (email and password) and a button that, when clicked, copies the values of the inputs to the clipboard. The **copyToClipboard** function uses the **document.getElementById** method to get the values of the inputs, concatenates them into a string, creates a temporary input element, sets its value to the string, selects it, and then executes the **document.execCommand("copy")** command to copy the value to the clipboard. Finally, it removes the temporary input element and alerts the user that the data has been copied.

```js
function copyToClipboard() {
  var email = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
  var data = "Email: " + email + "\nPassword: " + password;

  var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
  tempInput.style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px";
  tempInput.value = data;
  document.body.appendChild(tempInput);
  tempInput.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(tempInput);
  alert("Copied to clipboard: " + data);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="example@email.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value="password123">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy to Clipboard</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Slim-Jay1, your response is VERY USEFUL in a general sense, especially for someone new to js as a whole. Thank you. This, however, does not address my question. 

I can do what I need with a simple text box and js. It works. But like I tried to explain in my post, this is more about how to do it with Bootstrap version 5 components, simply because I don't have to worry about styling, resizing, etc.